# How arrays work in O(1) at the low level?

Tags: arrays, memory, time-complexity

So it is well known to access an element in an array takes only O(1) time since you can use a simple formula to determine the memory address of the element you want.

For instance, say you have an array starting from address 600 and want the 4th index, where each item in the array takes up 4 bits of space then we can directly access 600 + 4 * 4 = memory address 616.

The question is how? Like at the really low level won't it go "is this address 616? no, it is 600", therefore scans more to the right - "Is this address 616? no, it is 601" etc. Creating a low level O(n) access time.

I suppose my question is, how does the memory instantly access the address it needs to? Thanks for any responses :)

Comment: You mean like: this nulber is converted to binary and then the addressport lines are set (simultanously) to high or low depending on if the corresbonding bits are 1 or 0. The RAM is connected to the Addressbus, and provides then the data on the data bus. Or fo you wamt to know how RAM works?

Comment: @lalala honestly don't know much about the RAM. My question is how a memory address in the RAM can be accessed instantly rather than scanning through looking for some arbitrary address. Like if I have a book and want to open to page 616, I have to keep flicking through until I reach 616 I can't just open directly to it

Comment: @NightShade you want to know about direct accessing in RAM?

Comment: @SyedMehtabHassan I do not - i'm assuming that is what makes this possible

Comment: If you have any links or good explanation would be much appreciated :)

Comment: What do you want to know then ?

Comment: How the RAM is directly accessed so that if I want to look up a particular address it can do this instantly. How looking up address "620" would take me straight to 620 - Hope that makes sense

Comment: Actually if works on logical gates that allow to directly access particular address

Comment: https://tams.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/applets/hades/webdemos/40-memories/40-ram/ram-decoder24.html hope this doc will help you